# How to deploy project to the private server https://172.xx.xxx.xx

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, autodesk-forge

I would like to publish this project private server I have -

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter

The above project has been deployed on Heroku, with the following Callback URL & redirect_uri.

I am using a private server  https://172.xx.xxx.xx instead of Heroku so could you tell me how to deploy the application on the private server. And what should be the callback URL and redirect_uri for the same?

Please find the screenshot where I want to deploy the application where It mentioned the webroot -https://ibb.co/Kqf6tVd

Answer (score 0):

Both callback URL and redirect_uri are the same things. You need to replace `http://localhost:3000` with your private server base url.

```
//From
http://localhost:3000/api/forge/callback/oauth

//To

https://172.xx.xxx.xx /api/forge/callback/oauth
```

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter/blob/master/server/config.js#L26